# Cell Formulas Won't Read Unless I Hit Enter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a WB with multiple sheets, most sheets have a data-validation dropdown list in cell A4 (for whatever reason there are a couple that are just text). What I’m trying to do seemed relatively easy, whatever sheet I am on, when I select a value from the dropdown list, it will update that value on all of the sheets (except for the 2 I excepted). So if I select “Tom” from sheet 3, and then go to sheet 5 “Tom” will also be selected there.

Using my clunky code, I have managed to get this to (kinda) work. The problem is that the cell formulas that reference this (vlookups mostly) do not read it. I have to go to cell A4 and click into the formula bar, and hit enter. Then the formulas will read it.
I have been trolling message boards looking for solutions, but I’ve run out of ideas.

I’ve already:

-made sure autocalculation is on, made sure it isn’t text, made sure it isn’t circular

-made sure EnableCalculation is true (and also did true, then false, then true again), as well as application.calculate and tried various refreshes.

-I did the find a replace “=” of the formulas

I suspect that because the value is based on a variable (active-cell value), it’s got some kind of circular reference problem. In this latest version I tried to mitigate this by declaring it a variable and a string (too be honest, I’m grasping at straws), and before that I tried taking the active cell value, then copying and paste-special as just value.
I am very, very new to VBA so I am probably missing something dumb. I would really appreciate any suggestions regarding what I’m missing, because I have really hit a wall regarding things I’ve seen on this and other forums.

My current code is follows:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)


 If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A4")) Is Nothing Then

 Call SetDropdown

 End If

End Sub

Sub SetDropdown()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim acv As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    acv = ActiveCell.Value
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name And ws.Name <> "TEAM LIST" Then

    ws.Range("A4") = acv

    End If
   Next ws

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. May I see your file? If yes then can you share the file in a free file sharing site www.wikisend.com, or dropbox or onedrive and share the link here. remember to remove crucial perosnal details from the file before sharing the link here

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I needed to change the data and make sure everything worked. Sharelink: https://drive.google.com/file/d/188iA3e8xa2s9GuanXa3QH-SU-P4UaPpy/view?usp=sharing  Thank you so much for taking a look.

Comment: no worries. mention the exact steps that you are taking and what do you expect to happen and what exactly is happening

Comment: When I select a person from the dropdown (cell A4), the vlookups (sheet March) don't read what filters to cell A4.  I need to manually hit enter in that cell. Even with a sheet refresh, enable calculation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was overwriting some of the formula cells on hidden sheets with the loop. So I replaced the second part by running it as part of an array.

```
Sub SetDropdown()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

For Each ws In Sheets(Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "October", "November", "December"))
If ws.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then

ws.Range("A4") = ActiveCell.Value

End If

Next ws

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

This works for what I need it to do, but it does have the problem where even on the hidden sheets any changes to cell A4 create a workbook.worksheet event, so I need to find a way to change the sheetchange event to an array of specified sheets, but that is a separate question.